# How to test ag-Grid | Vue.js by using Java with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, ag-grid

I am trying to test ag-Grid | Vue.js and we have framework in Java with Selenium Webdriver.
I don't want deviate from existing framework. Is there is any way to test this with my current framework ?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your framework. Following things need to be evaluated

1. Is your driver static? If yes then you will have to change it to non static and modify project
2. Are you using testng? Its easy to use with grid
3. Do all your tests run in separate instances. If yes then you can run on grid easily

Projects are made but nobody cares in beginning to make it in a way that it can be implemented on grid.
Later one has to change a lot of things to configure this.